# I'm looking for better Google Slides Animation Settings - API or other

Tags: animation, google-slides-api

I want to get a partial arch to an animation so that my image stays reasonably horizontal on the stage as it travels from right to left.

Currently, the spin animation sets a full spin of 360 deg on any object and its slow speed is way too fast for my needs.

Is there a way to get access to the animation settings via the API or any other way?

I want to also slow the travel speed across the screen. The size of my image should not change to make this happen either.

Any ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: And what have you done already? Share some code.

Comment: Try to play with the functions in the [Transform Operations](https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/transform). It will allow you do manipulations in each element.